# How can I align a button at the bottom of a div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div called block_inside. In it, there are two divs, text_block and text_block_button.Button class in text_block_button shows and hides about class(paragraph) using jquery.text_block and text_block_button divs are inline. When I click button, div expands and shows "about" class.While showing and hiding about class, how can align button class to the bottom of block_inside div. Here is html codes:

```
<div class="block_inside">
  <div class="text_block">                   
    <p>Here is paragraph.  </p>
    <p class="about">Here is hidden paragraph.(more than 500 words.) </p>
  </div>
  <div class="text_block_button">
     <a class="button">About</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is css codes :

```
.block_inside {
   display:block;
   border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
   overflow:auto;
   padding-left: 10px;
}
.text_block {
   float:left;
   width:600px;
   margin-left:30px;
   padding: 0px;
}
.text_block_button {
   float: right;
   padding-right: 15px;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
   padding-left: 5px;
}
a.button {
   padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
   color: #ffffff;
   text-decoration: none;
   border:1px solid #32312f;
   text-transform:uppercase;
   font-size:9px;
   line-height:25px;    
}
```

Here is jquery code :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('p.about').hide();    
$('a.button').click(function() {
    $('p.about').toggle();
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Your *Question Title* does not actually match your question.

Comment: I don't know what you meant "align button class to the bottom of block_inside div". What's the point of "align a div to bottom of the page" (your question's title) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### *[demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/odotig/2/edit)*

```
.block_inside {
    position:relative; /*added*/
    /* ... */
}

.text_block_button {
    position:absolute;    /*added*/
    bottom:10px;          /*added*/
    right:10px;           /*added*/
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Ok. It works. I can edit title. What's your advice about title?

Comment: @kalaba2003 Exactly like in your question: **"how can I align a button at the bottom of a DIV"**  Thanks